# nginx rewrite not working... grab file with wildcard

Tags: linux, nginx, url-rewriting

The example below is what I have tried with no luck. I would like to redirect all files in the folder **/files/dump/** that start with **15EIP** to **/file-is-gone**

```
rewrite  ^/files/dump/15EIP(*.*)?$ /file-is-gone permanent;
```

Comment: You should learn regexps.

Comment: In this case you even don't need that stars. `rewrite ^/files/dump/15EIP /file-is-gone permanent;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen thanks... can you suggest a code site to learn regex?